# Trusted SharePoint Authority Sites

Tags: sharepoint

I'm looking for sites about SharePoint (MOSS 2007) that are trusted, where the writers have actually deployed large sites. Essentially, the Joel Spolsky of SharePoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joel Oleson was the original MS SharePoint Admin. He currently works at Quest. He worked on MS's SharePoint farms, which as you can imagine were MASSIVE.

http://www.sharepointjoel.com/default.aspx

Ben Curry co wrote the [MOSS 2007 Best Practices book](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Books/12197.aspx) (which is great) with Bill English.

http://sharepoint.mindsharpblogs.com/Ben/default.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Brian is right... Joel Oleson is THE definitive source (his original TechNet blog is here and has some of the best SharePoint posts): http://blogs.msdn.com/joelo/

A few more of my favorites:

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/default.aspx
http://msmvps.com/blogs/shane/
http://blogs.technet.com/wbaer/default.aspx
http://www.thorprojects.com/blog/default.aspx

-Sean